# How do I get notifications on new GitHub issues?

Tags: github

Right now, I miss quite some issues for my project hosted on GitHub. I am looking for a way which tells me of new issues. E-Mail would be fine, but those are only sent if I participated in a specific issue. IRC is also an option.

For both email and IRC, google spit out nothing helpful. Is this really not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [account notifications page](https://github.com/account/notifications), specifically the section under 'Issues'.

Comment: There is no such section (anymore?).

Comment: Maybe it has been renamed to "Notification Center"

Comment: there is no such section and no menu under Notification Center, either.

Comment: Still no such section (May, 2022). And this is the "accepted" answer. :/

Answer (score 12):

Actually, this one was a bit tricky. I didn't realize that notifications work slightly different with organizations. Sorry, I really forgot about this question and I can't tell you exactly how to configure it as this was a while ago - but if you stumble over this, and you are trying to get notifications for issues that are in organization projects, you should read this:

http://alexking.org/blog/2011/11/28/not-getting-github-notifications

whose key point is (a quote from Github support):

> Users in the Owners group don’t receive notifications. You need to create a normal team and add yourself to it to get notifications for that team’s repos.

Comment: How do I create a team? I found a guide, but that requires me to be in an organization, which I am not.
https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/creating-a-team

Answer (score 8):

I believe @boechat107 is correct about watching the repo. If you select **Watch > All Activity** in the upper right, you should start getting notifications:

[image: watch all activity]

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm late to this topic, but I've created a Chrome extension which allows you to receive notifications from GitHub repositories you can specify so you will not miss issues again.

Whenever an issue is opened on the repository(s) you've selected, a notification will be sent to you. Similarly, whenever someone creates a pull request, it will notify you as well.

Steps:

1. Install the Chrome extension [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-notifier/hoapibhhppbolnldjengllkcdbpbbgih)
2. Click on the installed Chrome Extension on the top right of Chrome and fill in your Git username
3. Enable permissions on your GitHub [here](https://github.com/apps/notifications)

Comment: Kudos, you're a hero for working around this breathtakingly strange behavior.

Comment: url **not found** error :(

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a team (other than `Owners`, e.g. `Project that will Change the World`), add yourself to it (along with any other GitHub members) and add a repositories that you would like to monitor. That should do.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will do it (this is for an enterprise organisation)...

[image: Github custom Watch - issues only]

Comment: I think what OP and I want is a way to get notified when a _new_ issue is opened, but for _existing_ issues only notifying when participating or mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I'm almost sure that it can be solved by "watching" a repository. Then, at the notification center, you can choose to receive notifications by email or just on the web.

Comment: Unfortunately, "watching" my own repository did not add its issue-creation events to my timeline, at least not in the mid-2018 version of Github.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it appears the only method of doing this now is to use Webhooks:

https://developer.github.com/webhooks/

For which you need a server to receive the payload when the event info (in this case, issues) is sent. You could use this project as a server:

https://github.com/rvagg/github-webhook

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for **IRC** notifications for *issues* (which are not enabled by default), you can enable them using the webhook API:

`curl -i -u YOURUSER -X GET https://api.github.com/repos/ORG/REPO/hooks
curl -i -u YOURUSER -X PATCH https://api.github.com/repos/ORG/REPO/hooks/IRC_HOOK_ID -d "{ \"add_events\": [\"push\", \"pull_request\", \"issues\"] }"`

Answer (score 0):

This question has been up for a while now and thoroughly answered in posts above, but Axibase has also designed a helpful tool which leverages the GitHub Webhook service and while it can certainly trigger an email response to new issues, it also has integration capabilities with many popular messenger services to send notifications anywhere the messenger is installed, like your smartphone for example.

The workflow here explains the mechanics of the tool itself, and this [guide](https://axibase.com/use-cases/integrations/github/issue-notification.html) takes you through the set-up step by step.

[image: ATSD Issue Integration]

The whole configuration process takes about 10 minutes. Good luck!

Disclaimer: I worked for the team that developed ATSD, which is the database used for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could set any web-monitoring program (such as my [WebCheck](http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/ssb22/setup/webcheck.html)) to alert you whenever your project page does not contain the string "Issues 0", but then leaving an issue open would get you alerted repeatedly. The current layout of the issues page can be scraped by looking for `<li id=` up until the next `</li>` (in WebCheck, `>{<li id=...</li>}` after your ...`/issues` URL should do it) but this may break when they change the layout.  It's a pity GitHub doesn't seem to have RSS or email notification options for all new issues raised against your own projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Slack, you can use [GitHub for Slack](https://slack.com/help/articles/232289568-GitHub-for-Slack) app to subscribe to all activities in your own repositories and receive notifications in any Slack channel

The `/github subscribe owner/repo` command will do the trick.

See more granular configurations for subscription, see [integrations/slack: Bring your code to the conversations you care about with the GitHub and Slack integration](https://github.com/integrations/slack#configuration).