# Missing notifications on github

Tags: github, notifications

I've followed the thread at:

[How do I get notifications on new GitHub issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186193/how-do-i-get-notifications-on-new-github-issues)

"Notification Center" has Email and Web checked for Participating and Watching and Notification Email is also correct.

But I'm not receiving any notifications for any pushes to my github repository at:

https://github.com/arun-gupta/javaee7-samples

Not even getting notifications for any issues. This is an individual project, not in a team.

How do I enable the basic notification so that I get an email for any pushes to the repository and updates to any of the issues ?

Comment: Have you checked your spam folder? I had the same issue, all notifications turned on but not receiving notifications. Turns out I had accidentally marked GitHub emails as spam a long time ago.

Answer (score 23):

I was having the same problem and believe it or not the following is what finally resolved it for me:

Checking both the "[x] Email" AND "[x] Web" options in the GitHub Notifications center of my GitHub Account Settings:

1. Login to your GitHub account.
2. Click the Account Settings icon on the top right.
3. Click the Notifications center category in the left column.
4. Make sure BOTH the "Email" AND "Web" options are checked.
5. Make sure the correct email address set to receive notifications.

In my case, I only had "Email" checked, but not "Web" (since I prefer doing everything via email rather than via crappy web page interfaces), and was never receiving any Email notifications (even though I had the "Email" option checked!).

But as soon as I checked the "Web" option as well (so that BOTH options were checked), VOILA!  I began receiving my email notifications again.

Go figure.

Comment: In 2020, this still appears to be a valid fix.  O_o

Comment: Just an addition, after following these instructions, and refreshing the notifications page, it won't show past notifications. It may seem obvious that it wouldn't, but at the same time, when normally looking at your notifications list it does show all past notifications unless you mark them done, so one may think it might show old ones after a refresh.

Comment: Looks like showing "done" notifications in the default inbox won't be a problem anymore. GitHub offers to remove all "done" notifications, which to me implies that's going to be the new default going forward. Maybe someone at Microsoft reads StackOverflow?

Comment: In 2023, I still have this problem and this workaround does not work (anymore? for me only? hard to tell). Extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 10):

Here is how I enabled notifications:

1. Go to the specific repository
2. Click on "Settings" on the right navigation bar
3. Click on "Service Hooks"
4. Click on "Email"
5. Enter the email address to receive notifications
6. Click on "Update Settings"

I was hoping the repo author would be automatically added to the notifications, but apparently not.

Comment: I noticed the "Settings" option doesn't exist if you don't have sufficient admin privileges on a repo. [The answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979113/735468) saying to go to your account settings and check Email and Web ended up solving my issue.

Answer (score 3):

go to https://github.com/settings/emails and check if your email is verified

after about 10 years of usage, github reset verification for my email for some reason

Comment: Same here, around the same date. I don't know what they are playing at, doing this silently.

Comment: haven't got any notification about that either

Comment: Confirmed fix for me! I used the proposed link. To my surprise, for one of the email addresses I had: "Undeliverable" and "Unverified". I click to verify, and the 2 brown messages disappeared.